# Failure to restart akka source that is created from Http response

Tags: scala, akka-stream, playframework-2.6

I have created WS client on play framework2.6 which connects to REST API. This rest API is continuously sending chunks/stream of data. But then for few seconds REST API server goes down and is again restarted.
I have written client to restart stream but it seems its not able to restart it.

```
    def employesCompany() = Action.async { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    val client =   ws.underlying
    
    val wsrequest: WSRequest = ws.url(playConfiguration.get[String]("employes.service.url"))

    val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = wsrequest.stream()

    futureResponse.flatMap { response =>
      val source: Source[ByteString, Any] = response.bodyAsSource
      val publisher = source.toMat(Sink.asPublisher(true))(Keep.right).run()
      val flow = Flow[ByteString].map(res => res.utf8String)
      val ns = Source.fromPublisher(publisher).via(flow)
      val restartSource = RestartSource.withBackoff(Duration.apply(1, "sec"), Duration.apply(3, "sec"), 0.2) { () =>
        ns.map {
          elem =>
            println(elem)
            elem
        }
      }
     
      Future.successful(Ok.chunked(restartSource via EventSource.flow).as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM))
    }
  }
```

I am facing below error:

```
ERROR] [12/20/2020 18:35:27.585] [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [RestartWithBackoffSource(akka://play-dev-mode)] **Restarting graph due to failure
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:368)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:891)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:277)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What's that `publisher` stuff for? It seems like that's just a complicated way to write `val ns = response.bodyAsSource.map(_.utf8String)`. And that is most likely wrong, because the boundaries of those `ByteString`s don't necessarily line up with the Unicode code unit boundaries, and even if they do, you probably want to handle e. g. lines, not random strings.

Comment: If you want to read lines from the source, you should use the `Framing` object to do it, i. e. 
`response.bodyAsSource.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\r\n"), maximumFrameLength = 100, allowTruncation = true)).map(_.utf8String)`

Comment: I added publisher to have multiple subscriber. Otherwise i was facing following error on restartsource  : [RestartWithBackoffSource(akka://play-dev-mode)] Restarting graph due to failure
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This publisher only supports one subscriber
        at play.shaded.ahc.com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.subscribe(HandlerPublisher.java:167)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$BatchingActorInputBoundary.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:115)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the request is already performed when you call `wsrequest.stream()`, but you want it to be performed later when the Source is materialized. You therefore need to delay the creation of the `Future` by not calling `wsrequest.stream` yourself but having Akka Stream do it.

I haven't worked with Akka Stream in a while, but something like this should work:

```scala
    val responseStream = Source.lazyFuture(() => wsrequest.stream())

    responseStream.flatMapConcat { response =>
      // the rest like before
```

Comment: i am using play2.6 . I cant see Source.lazyFuture method. I tried with Source.fromFuture but its not working

Comment: The `lazy` part is critical here. You can try upgrading to a newer Akka Stream version. Or perhaps it's possible to work around it with something like `Source.single(()).mapAsync(1)(_ => wsrequest.stream())`. Again, it's only about deferring the `wsrequest.stream()` call until the Source is materialized.